# Safari SVG transform-origin zoom animation

Tags: animation, svg, safari, css-transforms

I have an inline SVG which is being animated, however when you zoom in or out in the browser the object which is being rotated no longer rotates at its centre point.

It works fine in Chrome.

http://codepen.io/chrismorrison/pen/rmLXWw

```
#rays {
  animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I looked at this but having fixed values as px seemed to work as suggested below.

Comment: @Iceberg, no, finally we needed to adjust our site not to transform that SVG element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is late, but I found the same issue. If you use `transform-box: fill-box;`, the object will rotate on its axis properly in Safari.

Comment: I do have the same problem now, and I cannot solve with `transform:fill-box;`. And all the examples I find with this does behave wrong when I do zoom in/out in Safari. can you maybe send me an example which iteam I need to apply this?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue which I was able to resolve by adjusting the SVG's viewport attribute so that i could set

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

for the element I need to transform.

I've created a pen here showing the difference between the two: https://codepen.io/mbrrw/pen/NWxMamm

For a 20x20 circle, I changed the viewBox from 0,0,20,20 to -10, -10, 20, 20.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Brilliant! This does it! `transform-origin: 50%, 50%` is required however, as your CodePen uses.

Comment: Actually it looks like leaving out `transform-origin` entirely works fine in Safari. (Which is effectively what was happening in my previous comment as using `,` isn't valid for this property.)

Comment: hm thanks. is the pen / solution above wrong then?

Comment: Pen works great! With the solution update here both are working for me now :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question, but I've spent the last hour trying to come up with a solution and I wanted to share my solution in case it ever happens to anyone else!

Just like the OP, zooming in or out in Safari would screw up my transform-origins and they would be based on what the original size of the SVG pre-zoom. In my example, I was trying to rotate with a transform-origin of 100% 0%.

My fix (using Javascript): transform-origin: svgElem.currentScale * 100 + '% 0%';

Now, instead of having my rotate be off-axis, it's always in the right position.

Hopefully that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's implementation of `transform-origin` is different from other browsers.  Try using absolute coordinates.

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 201px 191px;
transform-origin: 201px 191px;
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your Safari problem, but it is good practice anyway. Especially if you want it to work in Firefox also.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it using `rem` unit to set `transform-origin`.

```
.logo-spinner path {
    animation: my-spinning-animation 1.8s infinite ease;
    transform-origin: 3rem 3rem;
}
```

Now, animation always remains centred while zooming-in/out on Safari.

(Except for the smallest zoom level which I think is acceptable)