# Issue when zooming in on SVG donut chart in Safari

Tags: svg, safari

I'm attempting to create a donut chart using SVG, and am running into a problem when viewing it in Safari. Here's a fiddle that shows the issue; I'll describe it in detail below:

https://jsfiddle.net/nijhazer/phy2ossh/

This fiddle shows a graphic comprised of two circles overlaid atop one another. The problem becomes apparent when a Safari user increases zoom size in her browser:

[image: SVG graphic rendered in Chrome and Safari at two different zoom levels]

Relevant HTML from the example:

```
<div class="donut-chart">
    <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle class="backdrop" cx="100" cy="100" r="65" fill="#d5d8d5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0"></circle>
        <circle class="progress" cx="100" cy="100" r="75" fill="none" stroke="lightgreen" stroke-width="20" style="stroke-dashoffset: 353.428875px;"></circle>
        <circle class="outer-ring" cx="100" cy="100" r="85" fill="none" stroke="#d5d8d5" stroke-width="1"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS from the example:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}
.donut-chart {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
svg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.progress {
    stroke-dasharray: 471.24;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: the issue is with how different browsers implement transform-origin. Especially now when some browsers did implement a lot of SVG 2.0 standard (Chrome). I would recommend you to avoid (for now) using transform-origin and do a work around. I will try to do it in the fiddle

Comment: what are you using to achieve "zoom"?

Comment: Not sure how exactly you implement zoom, I would need to know that to help

Comment: Zoom: Ctrl-Plus, or View > Zoom In.

Comment: Did you try solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642391/safari-svg-transform-origin-zoom-animation

Comment: I did, yeah. It didn’t work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see, I don't have safari to test but I would test also with adding transform origin to all the elements: .backdrop {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.outer-ring {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

Comment: did you find a way to fix this issue? I am having exactly the same issue.

Comment: As the pixel values in SVGs are relative ones; have you tried change the origin values to pixel values? (100px 100px)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps, but at I can read from the comments that people are blaming the CSS property transform-origin. In this example I moved the styling to attributes on the circle element. I also added `pathLength` to make it easier to control the progress bar.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.donut-chart {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="donut-chart">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http//www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="backdrop" cx="100" cy="100" r="65" fill="#d5d8d5"
      stroke="none" stroke-width="0" />
    <circle class="progress" cx="100" cy="100" r="75" fill="none"
      stroke="lightgreen" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="25 100"
      transform="rotate(-90 100 100)" pathLength="100" />
    <circle class="outer-ring" cx="100" cy="100" r="85" fill="none"
      stroke="#d5d8d5" stroke-width="1" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm [chrwahl's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681945/issue-when-zooming-in-on-svg-donut-chart-in-safari#72728484) is working (at least in MacOS/IOS safari versions (15.4) I've tested - Unfortunately, the support of functions may vary from version to version)

Another workaround could be to add a `translateX` offset before rotating like so:

```css
.donut-chart {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.progress {
  stroke-dasharray: 471.24;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(0px, 200px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="donut-chart">
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle class="backdrop" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="65" fill="#d5d8d5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    <circle class="progress" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="75" fill="none"  stroke="lightgreen" stroke-width="20" style="stroke-dashoffset: 353.428875px;"></circle>
    <circle class="outer-ring" cx="100" cy="100" r="85" fill="none" stroke="#d5d8d5" stroke-width="1"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This "hack" won't work combined with `transform-origin: 50% 50%`