# Transfer-origin does not seem to working in SVG on safari on zooming or scaling issue in safari

Tags: animation, svg, transform, scaling

I am trying to rotate partially filled circle on top of other circle in infinite animation,but on zooming In and Out it did not align outer blue filled circle properly with the inner circle.i also tried with `transform-box: fill-box` but that also did not work.

CSS used for the rotation

```
    @keyframes rotation {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);

        }
        to {
           transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
.cls-5 {
       transform-origin: center center;
       //transform-box:fill-box;
        animation: rotation 1.5s infinite linear;
    }
```

[JSBin demo link](https://jsbin.com/pijuwopogu/edit?html,css,output)

[wrong image for safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcTj3.png)

[Correct image for safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFLGu.png)

Comment: perhaps safari simply hasn't implemented transform-box

Comment: i don't think transform-box will resolve issue here,as it is not used in other browser also

Comment: What other browser? Chrome and Firefox support transform-box.

Comment: in firefox and chrome i did not use  transform-box property too,in that case also it is working

Answer (score 0):

This is a Possible duplicate of [Safari SVG transform-origin zoom animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43642391/2624372)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you think this question already has an answer elsewhere feel free to flag it as a duplicate, otherwise please use this space to provide a complete answer to the question. Also it is always better to provide the code inside the answer rather than linking to another site hosting the code.